# Update normals of animated skinned mesh in three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js, shader, normals

I have a simple animated model, animated throught skinning, and I am giving it a `ShaderMaterial` which displays its normals:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(vNormal, 1.0);
```

https://codepen.io/marco_fugaro/pen/ZEEBjKz?editors=0010

The problem is the normals aren't updated with the skinning of the model, and they always stay the same from the object's non animated position (see `VertexNormalsHelper`).

How do I get the normals to update, or how do i get the animated vertices' normals?

`model.geometry.computeVertexNormals()` doesn't work

[image: model]

Comment: Using a `ShaderMaterial` doesn't seem like it's going to show you normals. Maybe use the [`MeshNormalMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshNormalMaterial). Otherewise if you want to modify the standard materials you need to use `Material.onBeforeCompile` so that you get all the skinning and other features. There's on example of using `onBeforeCompile` [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-indexed-textures.html)

Comment: I'm doing other things with the normals, so I need to use a custom shader. Do you know what should I inject in the shader in the `onBeforeCompile`?

Comment: Done, thank you! Your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up monkeyPatching the `MeshNormalMaterial` vertex shader, and removing the logic that the normals are relative to the camera, here is the final code:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import normalVert from 'three/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/normal_vert.glsl'

// like MeshNormalMaterial, but the normals are relative to world not camera
const normalMaterialGlobalvert = normalVert.replace(
  '#include <defaultnormal_vertex>',
  THREE.ShaderChunk['defaultnormal_vertex'].replace(
    'transformedNormal = normalMatrix * transformedNormal;',
    // take into consideration only the model matrix
    'transformedNormal =  mat3(modelMatrix) * transformedNormal;'
  )
)
```

And then use it like:

```js
mesh.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: normalMaterialGlobalvert,
  fragmentShader: `
    varying vec3 vNormal;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vNormal, 1.0);
    }
  `,
})
```

Thanks [gman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman) for pointing me in the right direction!